# share data between parent and child components using service file

Tags: angular5

I have created a service in which I am getting and setting the value of a parameter and making it shareable to other component but unfortunately it is showing me undefined. I am not getting the bug that is in it.

Code of service:-

```
Id: any;

setId(Id:any) {
    this.Id = Id;
  }

  getId() {
    return this.Id;
  }
```

I am calling setId() method from parent component and I have checked it is coming properly but as my child component loads value gets lost in the service variable.

Comment: are you using angularjs or angular?

Comment: How you are connect this service? It is possible that several instances of the service are initialized. Can you show you module providers?

Comment: Hey @mast3rd3mon  I am using angular 5

Comment: please use the correct angular tag for angular questions

Comment: Is it possible that you added the service as a provider in two different modules?

Comment: yes, I used this service several places.